# i want to include all controllers, views and models of a gem into my host application. is it possible in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

There is a gem I included in my project. I want to customize it. I don't know how. I can customize it depending on requirement only if I have all the controller views in my host application.

Is there a way I can copy all the code into my application? How to configure routes and all...?

Will it work if I copy all the controllers and views and models?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,a Rails [Engine](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) is exactly what you're looking for. It's a form of a gem that includes all of the above in a host app.

> Engines can be considered miniature applications that provide functionality to their host applications. A Rails application is actually just a "supercharged" engine, with the Rails::Application class inheriting a lot of its behavior from Rails::Engine.